# Does DXA support Extended Keyword Models?

Tags: dxa, web8.5, c#, dxa2.2, dxa-dotnet

I am using dxa 2.2 (.net) and I created a custom Keyword Model `BaseKeywordModel` that extends `KeywordModel`. When DXA tries to map a published component that has a keyword field to a model that uses the `BaseKeywordModel` for its keyword property it fails.

I've identified the issue. The problem occurs in the `DefaultModelBuilder` class when trying to do this:

```
mappedValues.Add(MapKeyword((KeywordModelData) fieldValues, targetType, mappingData.Localization));
```

The problem here is that `mappedValues` is a Generic List of `BaseKeywordModel` and DXA tries to add a `KeywordModel` to the list, causing an exception.

This test method causes the same issue:

```csharp
[Test]
public void ModelBuilderMappedValuesTest()
{
    var mappedValues = typeof(BaseKeywordModel).CreateGenericList();
    var kwdModel = new KeywordModel
    {
        Id = "Test",
        ExtensionData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    };
    try
    {
        mappedValues.Add(kwdModel);
        Assert.Equals(mappedValues.Count, 1);
    }
    catch
    {
        Assert.Fail("Error adding keyword model to list of extended keyword models");
    }

}
```

This is the `BaseKeywordModel` class:

```csharp
[Include("Title", "Description", "Key")]
public class BaseKeywordModel: KeywordModel    {    }
```

I need to be able to use my own class for Keywords and was wondering whether I am doing anything wrong or this is some kind of bug in the `ModelBuilder`.

It seems that by adding a Metadata Schema to the Keyword, the `ModelBuilder` is capable of creating the right instance of the object, i.e. `BaseKeywordModel`.

With that said, and kinda mimicking what the code does when there's a metadata schema associated to the keyword, instead of the code the `ModelBuilder` uses now:

```csharp
if (keywordModelData.SchemaId == null)
{
    result = new KeywordModel
    {
        ExtensionData = keywordModelData.ExtensionData
    };
}
```

If it would use this code:

```csharp
if (keywordModelData.SchemaId == null)
{
    result = (KeywordModel) targetType.CreateInstance();
    result.ExtensionData = keywordModelData.ExtensionData;
}
```

We should be able to use our own Keyword Extended Models without the need of a metadata schema. That change shouldn't cause any regression issues as the code already does its due diligence check:

```csharp
if (typeof(KeywordModel).IsAssignableFrom(targetType)) { ... }
```

Will try to open a support ticket to see if I can get a hotfix in place. Of course, if you guys know a different way or see I am doing something wrong, please let me know.

Comment: This is a beautifully detailed report. Thanks!
Maybe the fastest way to get this fixed is a pull request with your [GitHub issue](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/issues/76), since you already know what needs to be fixed.

Comment: Same issue occurs with RichText sub classes. Will be doing a separate pull request for that

Comment: RichText similar issue: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20327/does-dxa-support-extended-richtext-models-is-this-by-design/20328#20328

Comment: The assumption was that you create a `KeywordModel` subclass if you want to add properties which map to Keyword metadata. Can you elaborate on why you want to create a subclass for Keywords which don’t have metadata?

Comment: @RickPannekoek, because my KeywordModel uses an custom "Include" attribute, that I use for serialization and it can potentially have other properties, for example helper methods that can do different things based on the 'Key' for example, load additional external data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I mentioned in the question seems to be the answer. I have created a pull request in order to introduce the fix and potentially get hotfix out of it.

https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/pull/77

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Much appreciated! However, some expectation management: we strive to incorporate community-reported issues with PR in the next DXA release. Since DXA 2.2 has been released, we’re talking DXA 3.0.