# Does DXA support extended RichText Models? Is this by design?

Tags: dxa, web8.5, c#, dxa2.2, dxa-dotnet

I already reported/asked about a similar issue with extended Keyword Models here:

[Does DXA support Extended Keyword Models?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20292/does-dxa-support-extended-keyword-models)

The same problem occurs if we try to extend from `Sdl.Web.Common.Models.RichText`and use that sub class in our own models, the `DefaultModelBuilder` mapping fails.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to subclass `RichText` in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I see a possible solution and will be what I will add to my pull request. These methods are the ones causing issues:

```csharp
protected virtual object MapString(string stringValue, Type targetType, string pageContextId, Localization localization) 
...
if (targetType == typeof(RichText))
{
    return new RichText(stringValue);
}
```

and

```csharp
protected virtual object MapRichText(RichTextData richTextData, Type targetType, Localization localization)
...
if (targetType == typeof(RichText))
{
    return new RichText(fragments);
}
```

After looking deeper at the code, a potential solution would be to replace those *if's* with these respectively:

**On the MapString method:**

```csharp
if (typeof(RichText).IsAssignableFrom(targetType))
{
    var richText = targetType.CreateInstance(stringValue);
    return richText;
}
```

**On the MapRichText method:**

```csharp
if (typeof(RichText).IsAssignableFrom(targetType))
{
    var customRichText = targetType.CreateInstance(fragments);
    return customRichText;
}
RichText richText = new RichText(fragments);
return richText.ToString();
```

So unless anybody has a reason for this not to be feasible, i.e. extending RichText models, I will go ahead and create a new (issue) and Pull Request to try to get my code in place.

Let me know your thoughts.

**Update: Issue has been reported and pull request submitted: **
https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/issues/78

Comment: This same issue can potentiall occur with `Link` sub-classes and `Tag` sub-classes

Comment: And MultimediaItem iirc

Comment: The `Tag` class is legacy from early DXA versions. Class `KeywordModel` was introduced later as a (concrete) base class. Class `MediaItem` is an abstract base class, so you must use subclasses.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to suclass `Link`?

Comment: Just a thought - could you have done this by deriving from DefaultModelBuilder into your own Model Builder class and providing your own implementations of those methods in the derived class? I assume that's was the intention behind marking them as virtual.

Comment: @Neil, I will try that, for sure (specially for support purposes). However I think the current DefaultModelBuilder needs to support this too, as it does with other models.

Comment: @Neil, thanks for the tip, that's the _right_ way to do it. It is much cleaner now. And actually I was able to implement Dependency Injection in my Custom Model Builder, which opens the door for a new world of possibilities :D

Comment: @Rick, similar to the Keyword model scenario, a RichText sub class might require additional functionality and/or properties, such as html manipulation, or whatever other properties and methods it might need. In my case specifically to decorate the class with attributes for de/serialization

Comment: @Jaime - great!